# Importing JSON from phpMyAdmin into MongoDB gives error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)

Tags: json, mongodb, phpmyadmin

I have a JSON file exported from PhpMyAdmin in the form:

```
[{"BASICCHAR":"<control>","CATEGORY_JDOID":"0","CHARNUM":"0",....
```

all on a single line.

I'm trying to import from the command line with:

```
mongoimport HOST -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --db DBNAME --collection COLL --jsonArray --file FILENAME
```

but I get:

```
error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)
try 'mongoimport --help' for more information
```

I don't understand the reference to "positional argument(s)". Is it something in the JSON data that is confusing it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the 'positional arguments' was referring to my first HOST value. In fact the command should have been:

```
mongoimport -h HOST -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --db DBNAME --collection COLL --jsonArray --file FILENAME
```

with the **-h** included before the hostname.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but in my case it was using a `-` for a long option instead of a `--`. This appears to be the default error message when arguments are malformed, which is a bit confusing.